# Solr stemming together with fuzziness returns 0 results

Tags: solr, lucene, fuzzy-search, stemming, fuzzy

- SOLR 6.4.1

we are facing an issue with solr fuzziness & stemming via SnowballPorterFilterFactory for German2.

```
    <fieldType name="text_de_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="de_DE"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymFilterFactory" managed="de_DE"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1"
                      generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
                      catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Additionally in our query configuration we add "~" for fuzziness.

```
{q=field_text_de_de_mv:XYZ~}
```

As query parser the standard query parse aka. lucene is used.

First of all, our assumption is that fuzziness is applied before stemming via SnowballPorter. Meaning:

```
SearchTerm: Xyzker ->(query) Xyzker~ (check for (XyzKer, XyzXer, Xyzer etc..)) -> stem(Xyzxer, Xyzxer... ) HIT -> deliver result
```

Is this correct? 
Are there any recommendations to use fuzziness with, or without stemming (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#TheStandardQueryParser-FuzzySearches)?

So now to the actual behaviour:

Indexing "Xyzker" with fieldtype text_de_de, so stemming is applied. 
Query for "Xzyser" (containing one typo s for k). 
Expected result: a hit for "Xyzker" when fuzziness is on default (~).

We get 0 results. Can somebody elaborate? Or give some hints/readings? I already checked out Solr in action.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing a fuzzy search (or a wildcard search, etc. - any search for one term could evaluate to multiple tokens on the index side), the analysis chain is not applied (except for [filters that are multi term aware](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/analyzers.html#Analyzers-AnalysisforMulti-TermExpansion), which usually are the LowercaseFilter and nothing more).

The solution is usually to normalize the tokens on their way in, possibly through a filter written specific to the data you're searching.